# Python 2.7 - Compare two text files and write only the unique values from first file

Tags: python, python-2.7, set, difflib, file-comparison

I am trying to do the following. Compare two text files ( Masterfile and usedfile) and write the unique values(not common in both) of Masterfile to third file (Newdata ). Both files have one word in each line. example:

Masterfile content

```
Johnny
transfer
hello
kitty
```

usedfile content

```
transfer
hello
```

expected output in Newdata

```
Johnny
kitty
```

I have two solutions but both have problem

solution 1:This gives information like -,+ prefixed to the data final output.

```
import difflib

with open(r'C:\Master_Data.txt','r') as masterfile:
    with open(r'C:\Used_Data.txt','r') as usedfile:
        with open(r'c:\Ready_to_use.txt','w+') as Newdata:
            tempmaster = masterfile.readlines()
            tempusedfile = usedfile.readlines()
            d = difflib.Differ()
            diff = d.compare(tempmaster,tempusedfile)
            for line in diff:
                Newdata.write(line)
```

solution 2: I tried using set ,it shows fine when I use print statement but don't know how to write to a file.

```
with open(r'C:\Master_Data.txt','r') as masterfile:
    with open(r'C:\Used_Data.txt','r') as usedfile:
        with open(r'c:\Ready_to_use.txt','w+') as Newdata:
           difference = set(masterfile).difference(set(usedfile))
           print difference
```

Can anyone suggest

1. how I can correct the solution 2 to write to a file.
2. can I use difflib to accomplish the task
3. Any better solution to achieve the end result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

**1)** You can use solution 2 to write to a file by adding this:

```
difference = set(masterfile).difference(set(usedfile))
[Newdata.write(x) for x in difference]
```

This is a shorthand way of doing this:

```
for x in difference:
    Newdata.write(line)
```

**However**, this will just write each element in the `difference` set to the `Newdata` file. If you use this method make sure that you have the correct values in your `difference` array to start with.

**2)** I wouldn't bother using difflib, it's an extra library that isn't required to do something small like this.

**3)** This is how I would do it, without using any libraries and simple comparison statements:

```
with open(r'Master_Data.txt','r') as masterdata:
with open(r'Used_Data.txt','r') as useddata:
    with open(r'Ready_to_use.txt','w+') as Newdata:

        usedfile = [ x.strip('\n') for x in list(useddata) ] #1
        masterfile = [ x.strip('\n') for x in list(masterdata) ] #2

        for line in masterfile: #3
            if line not in usedfile: #4
                Newdata.write(line + '\n') #5
```

Here's the explaination:

First I just opened all the files like you did, just changed the names of the variables. Now, here are the pieces that I've changed

`#1` - This is a shorthanded way of looping through each line in the `Used_Data.txt` file and remove the `\n` at the end of each line, so we can compare the words properly.

`#2` - This does the same thing as `#1` except with the `Master_Data.txt` file

`#3` - I loop through each line in the `Master_Data.txt` file

`#4` - I check to see if the line is `not in` the `masterfile` array also exists in the `usedfile` array.

`#5` - If the `if` statement is true, then the line from `Master_File.txt` we are checking does not appear in `Used_Data.txt`, so we write it to the `Ready_to_use.txt` file using the call `Newdata.write(line + '\n')`. The reason we need the `'\n'` after is so the file knows to start a new line next time we try to write something.

Comment: thanks. Also this is a general question, can you tell why we don't have to read the lines using .read() when we use list or set with fileobject ?

Comment: I actually don't know. I would have used a small loop to read the file lines as that is the way I learned it but I noticed that you used `set(masterfile)` in your code and thought it better to keep with what you knew

Answer (score 0):

If the data isn't too big you can use two lists to have the lines and compare each element of one list to the other like:

```
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as masterfile:
        with open('test2.txt', 'r') as usedfile:
            with open('test3.txt', 'w+') as Newdata:
                mlines = masterfile.read().splitlines()
                ulines = usedfile.read().splitlines()
                for line in mlines:
                    if ulines.__contains__(line) == False:
                        Newdata.write(line + '\n')
                for line1 in ulines:
                    if mlines.__contains__(line1) == False:
                        Newdata.write(line1 + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Solution 2:

```
with open(r'C:\Master_Data.txt','r') as masterfile:
    with open(r'C:\Used_Data.txt','r') as usedfile:
        difference = set(masterfile).difference(usedfile)

with open('Ready_to_use.txt', 'w') as file_out:
    for line in difference:
        file_out.write(line)
```