# How to comparing two big files on unique strings using fgrep/comm?

Tags: python, bash, shell, compare, comm

I have two files. A file disk.txt contains 57665977 rows and database.txt 39035203 rows;

To test my script I made two example files:

```bash
$ cat database.txt
01fffca9-05c8-41a9-8539-8bb2f587cef2
02fffd0d-fbcf-4759-9478-cfd32c987101
03fffd54-8d62-4555-a4ce-370f061048d5
04fffdb6-24f9-4b98-865f-ce32bc44872c
05fffe0c-2b9d-47fa-8ee9-2d20d0b28334
06fffea1-46f2-4aa2-93b9-be627189e38b
10ffff8a-cc20-4a2b-b9b2-a3cbc2000e49
11ffffaf-fd54-49f3-9719-4a63690430d9
12ffffc6-4ea8-4336-bdf1-e2d9d71a1c29

$ cat disk.txt
01fffca9-05c8-41a9-8539-8bb2f587cef2
02fffd0d-fbcf-4759-9478-cfd32c987101
03fffd54-8d62-4555-a4ce-370f061048d5
04fffdb6-24f9-4b98-865f-ce32bc44872c
05fffe0c-2b9d-47fa-8ee9-2d20d0b28334
06fffea1-46f2-4aa2-93b9-be627189e38b
07fffeed-5a0b-41f8-86cd-e6d99834c187
08ffff24-fb12-488c-87eb-1a07072fc706
09ffff29-ba3d-4582-8ce2-80b47ed927d1
10ffff8a-cc20-4a2b-b9b2-a3cbc2000e49
```

What I try to accomplish is to create files for the differences.

1. A file with the uniques in disk.txt (so I can delete them from disk)
2. A file with the uniques in database.txt (So I can retrieve them from backup and restore)

### Using `comm` to retrieve differences

I used `comm` to see the differences between the two files. Sadly `comm` also returns the duplicates after some uniques.

```bash
$ comm -13 database.txt disk.txt
07fffeed-5a0b-41f8-86cd-e6d99834c187
08ffff24-fb12-488c-87eb-1a07072fc706
09ffff29-ba3d-4582-8ce2-80b47ed927d1
10ffff8a-cc20-4a2b-b9b2-a3cbc2000e49
```

```bash
$ comm -13 database.txt disk.txt
07fffeed-5a0b-41f8-86cd-e6d99834c187
08ffff24-fb12-488c-87eb-1a07072fc706
09ffff29-ba3d-4582-8ce2-80b47ed927d1
10ffff8a-cc20-4a2b-b9b2-a3cbc2000e49
```

using `comm` on one of these large files takes 28,38s. This is really fast but is solely not a solution.

### using `fgrep` to strip duplicates from `comm` result

I can use `fgrep` to remove the duplicates from the `comm` result and this works on the example.

```bash
$ fgrep -vf duplicate-plus-uniq-disk.txt duplicate-plus-uniq-database.txt
11ffffaf-fd54-49f3-9719-4a63690430d9
12ffffc6-4ea8-4336-bdf1-e2d9d71a1c29
```

```bash
$ fgrep -vf duplicate-plus-uniq-database.txt duplicate-plus-uniq-disk.txt
07fffeed-5a0b-41f8-86cd-e6d99834c187
08ffff24-fb12-488c-87eb-1a07072fc706
09ffff29-ba3d-4582-8ce2-80b47ed927d1
```

On the large files this script just crashed after a while. So it is not a viable option to solve my problem.

### Using python `difflib` to get uniques

I tried using this python script I got from [BigSpicyPotato's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43700149/python-2-7-compare-two-text-files-and-write-only-the-unique-values-from-first) on a different post

```python
import difflib
with open(r'disk.txt','r') as masterdata:
    with open(r'database.txt','r') as useddata:
        with open(r'uniq-disk.txt','w+') as Newdata:
            usedfile = [ x.strip('\n') for x in list(useddata) ]
            masterfile = [ x.strip('\n') for x in list(masterdata) ]

            for line in masterfile:
                if line not in usedfile:
                    Newdata.write(line + '\n')
```

this also works on the example. Currently this is still running and takes up alot my CPU power.. Looking at the uniq-disk file it is really slow aswell..

### Question

Any faster / better option I can try in bash / python? I was aswell looking into `awk` / `sed` to maybe parse the the results form `comm`.

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso, thanks for the feedback. I adjusted the post with more similar sample inputs to what my files contain. Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @markp-fuso `comm --version`` is not working for me.. I am guessing I run an outdated version. I use comm on macosx 12.2 ``man comm`` does not contain any mention of how to get the version number. The manually seems to be written on January 26, 2005.

Comment: you mention the `comm` takes `28,38s` to run ... is that the time for *each* of the `comm` calls or is that the total/combined time it takes to run the 2 `comm` calls?

Comment: To answer your question the data and output I provide is copied directly from console. (before I only added the * and ^ to make the problem more clear). I just reran my test and it is still an issue.

Comment: @markp-fuso the 28,38s is on my large files for one of the comm commands.

Comment: wondering the same thing as KamilCuk ... are there any other characters in your files for the lines that start with `10fff` (even an extra space at the end of one line will generate the output you're showing); consider running `grep -h 10fff database.txt disk.txt  | od -c` ...  should show each character for both lines; add this output to the question if you're not sure how to read the `od -c` output

Comment: ah I did have a space behind the last line of my example...

Comment: Well that white space did make me learn alot... Thanks for your help @markp-fuso Much appriciated!

Comment: further performance improvement would (obviously) come from replacing the current 2x `comm` calls with a single call of 'something' that runs on the same order as a single `comm`; KamilCuk's `join | ...` suggestion may work; a custom `python` or `awk` script that processes the 2 input files in parallel would also work (obviously) with a bit more coding ....

Answer (score 2):

From `man comm`, `*` added by me:

```
Compare **sorted** files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
```

You have to sort the files for `comm`.

```
sort database.txt > database_sorted.txt
sort disk.txt > disk_sorted.txt
comm -13 database_sorted.txt disk_sorted.txt
```

See `man sort` for various speed and memory enhancing options, like `--batch-size`, `--temporary-directory` `--buffer-size` `--parallel`.

> A file with the uniques in disk.txt
> A file with the uniques in database.txt

After sorting, you can implement your python program that compares line-by-line the files and write to mentioned files, just like `comm` with custom output. Do not store whole files in memory.

You can also do something along this with `join` or `comm --output-delimiter=' '`:

```
join -v1 -v2 -o 1.1,2.1 disk_sorted.txt database_sorted.txt | tee >(
    cut -d' ' -f1 | grep -v '^$' > unique_in_disk.txt) |
    cut -d' ' -f2 | grep -v '^$' > unique_in_database.txt
```

Comment: Hi KamilCuk, I already sorted my files but comm still returns duplicates between files. Your other suggestion seems to work on my example files. So I will now try it on my real files. :)

Comment: Check the duplicate lines with `hexdump -C` for unprintable characters.

Comment: How does ``hexdump -C`` work exactly does it give an error if it find unprintable characters?

Comment: `work exactly` It displays file contents in hexadecimal and other forms. `does it give an error if it find unprintable characters` no, you have to go through the output manually.

Answer (score 0):

`comm` does exactly what I needed. I had a white space behind line 10 of my disk.txt file. therefor comm returned it as a unique string. Please check @KamilCuk answer for more context about sorting your files and using comm.

Answer (score 0):

```
 # WHINY_USERS=1 isn't trying to insult anyone - 
 # it's a special shell variable recognized by 
 # mawk-1 to presort the results

 WHINY_USERS=1 {m,g}awk '

 function phr(_) { 
    print \
          "\n Uniques for file : { "\
     (_)" } \n\n -----------------\n" 
 } 
 BEGIN {
          split(_,____) 
        split(_,______) 
     PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_asc"
                        FS = "^$"
 } FNR==NF {
    ______[++_____]=FILENAME 
 }       {
      if($_ in ____) { 
          delete ____[$_] 
      } else {
          ____[$_]=_____ ":" NR 
      }
 } END  { 
    for(__ in ______) { 
         phr(______[__])
             _____=_<_
         for(_ in ____) {
             if(+(___=____[_])==+__) {
                 print "  ",++_____,_,
                       "(line "(substr(___,
                       index(___,":")+!!__))")" 
     }   }   }
 printf("\n\n") } ' testfile_disk.txt testfile_database.txt
```

|

```
 Uniques for file : { testfile_disk.txt } 

 -----------------

   1 07fffeed-5a0b-41f8-86cd-e6d99834c187 (line 7)
   2 08ffff24-fb12-488c-87eb-1a07072fc706 (line 8)
   3 09ffff29-ba3d-4582-8ce2-80b47ed927d1 (line 9)

 Uniques for file : { testfile_database.txt } 

 -----------------

   1 11ffffaf-fd54-49f3-9719-4a63690430d9 (line 18)
   2 12ffffc6-4ea8-4336-bdf1-e2d9d71a1c29 (line 19)
```